# How to make logo appear on navbar depending on width change in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

So, I am trying to make this navbar in ReactJS and CSS, where I want a logo to appear on navbar only when the width size is less than 960px. 
**Required Behavior** 
Logo to appear on navbar only when the innerwidth is less or equal to 960px. 
**Current Behavior** 
Logo is not hidden and is displayed all the times. Changing the width but the logo is not hiding.
What I have done so far:

```
import React from "react";
import "./navbar.css";
import NavbarItems from "./navbarItems";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Image } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import logo from "../images/logo.png";

export default function Navbar(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <nav className='NavbarItems'>
        {window.innerWidth < 960 ? (
          <div>
            <Image src={logo} className='navbar-logo' />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className='navbar-logo'></div>
        )}
        <div
          className='menu-icon'
          onClick={() => props.setIsMenuOpen(!props.isMenuOpen)}
        >
          <i className={props.isMenuOpen ? "fas fa-times" : "fas fa-bars"}></i>
        </div>
        <ul className={props.isMenuOpen ? "nav-menu active" : "nav-menu"}>
          {NavbarItems.map((item, index) => {
            if (item.isLink)
              return (
                <li key={index}>
                  <Link
                    className={item.cname}
                    to={item.url}
                    onClick={() => props.setIsMenuOpen(false)}
                  >
                    {item.title}
                  </Link>
                </li>
              );
            else
              return (
                <li key={index}>
                  <a
                    className={item.cname}
                    href={item.url}
                    onClick={() => props.setIsMenuOpen(false)}
                  >
                    {item.title}
                  </a>
                </li>
              );
          })}
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </>
  );
}
```

the CSS file

```
.NavbarItems {
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: "Fjord One";
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #010108;
  color: white;
}

.nav-menu {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, auto);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 97vw;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

.nav-links {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}

.nav-links:hover {
  background-color: #09071a;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  color: white;
}

.fa-bars {
  color: #cfcfcf;
}

.nav-links-mobile {
  display: none;
}

.menu-icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .NavbarItems {
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .nav-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 540px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: -100%;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
  }

  .nav-menu.active {
    background: #010108;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .nav-links {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
  }
  .nav-links:hover {
    background-color: #09071a;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: white;
  }
  .navbar-logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    max-width: 200px;
  }
  .menu-icon {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: translate(-100%, 60%);
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .fa-times {
    color: #cfcfcf;
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
}
```

Any kind of suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I solved it this way.
First I put no className in the empty div. Then in my CSS file, I did the following

```
.navbar-logo {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 960px){
.navbar-logo {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    max-width: 250px;
  }
}
```

the answer was in CSS all along.